# xcode - how to get type of NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, typeof

I am getting `NSObject * myObject` on a receiver's side. Sender can send me `(NSArray *)` or `(NSDictionary *)` type.
How can I check if I get `(NSArray *)`?

Something like:

```
NSObject * myObject;
....
if (typeof(myObject) == (NSArray *))
{

} else if (typeof(myObject) == (NSDictionary *))
```

Any idea?

Comment: Use kindOfclass instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`-isKindOfClass:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass%3a)

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    // Array
} else if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    // Dictionary
}
```